# Decompiling apk using apktool

Tags: apk, instagram, decompiling, apktool

I need to decompile & recompile an apk on windows...
I am following this link [Reverse Engineer APK](http://blog.will3942.com/reverse-engineering-instagram)

The issue is I can't find the file that makes requests (refer to above link)"Find the file that makes requests grep -r "RequestUtil.java" "
I tried using WindowsGrep software, but unable to find such file.

I don't know if I am on the wrong track.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: No, you are on the wrong track. There is a modern alternative to this APKTool->dex2jar->JD-GUI route!

Just try open-source APK and DEX decompiler called Jadx: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jadx/files/ 
It has also online version here: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

Answer (score 1):

After decompiling apk, change directory to the com.instagram.android/smali: `cd com.instagram.android/smali`

Search RequestUtil.java by Windows search or following command in command prompt: `dir /s *RequestUtil.java*`

If the `RequestUtil.java` not found, it does not exists! Make sure you decompile the correct version of apk.

Comment: I had tried this...but doesn't work!!!
I am trying to pull the apk from device as well...but unable to do so :(
If you can help, wud be great

Comment: Okay, I even pulled the apk from android device as well!!
But still unable to find the file

Comment: Are you sure you decompile the correct version of apk? It seems you try to decompile the newer version of the apk and `RequestUtil.java` removed from the source by provider.

Comment: Then which version I should decompile?